# How can we programmatically add entities to a trust relationship in AWS role?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is there a way to edit the trust relationship of an existing role in AWS using python? for STS assume role I needed to automate the process of creating roles. these roles will be created through a cloud formation and I needed to add arn of one role to other role's trust relationship.

Comment: it sounds like there are two different approaches being described here: (i) using cloudformation to create roles (ii) using boto3 to create roles. Which do you want to do?

Comment: creation part I can handle. I wanted to edit the trust relationship of an existing role.

Comment: and you are asking how to do this in python?

Comment: yeah @LucasRoberts I wanted it to be in python otherwise if there is a possibility to do it in any other language please give me the details of it.

Comment: the reason I ask is because the phrase: `these roles will be created through a cloud formation ...` which reads as though you want to create the roles in a cloudformation template.